# Android view flipper with centered top title

Tags: android, viewflipper

I want to make an app with flip animations like Android Market app.It will have title at top center and it will flip with the page.Are there any source code or library for this?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to desing your view accordingly. I would recommend using fragments.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html Is that the information what i have to get ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but yes, veiw groups would also be a solution.